# Add Group Subheader in R Dataframe and save to Excel

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to add subheaders within a table. This is the format of my dataframe currently.

| Parameter | Number | HC | Percentage | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 324 | 324 | 0% | 1 |
| B | 173 | 12902 | 1.3% | 1 |
| C | 68 | 1166 | 5.8% | 2 |
| D | 396 | 12902 | 3.1% | 3 |
| E | 58% | - | - | 3 |
| D | -100% | - | - | 4 |

I am looking for a structure as shown below, which I will export to Excel with openxlsx and writeData.

| Parameter | Number | HC | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 |  |  |  |
| A | 324 | 324 | 0% |
| B | 173 | 12902 | 1.3% |
| Group 2 |  |  |  |
| C | 68 | 1166 | 5.8% |
| Group 3 |  |  |  |
| D | 396 | 12902 | 3.1% |
| E | 58% | - | - |
| Group 4 |  |  |  |
| D | -100% | - | - |

This is the code I have been working on, but I am not getting the result that I want.

```
# Add group subheaders and remove group column
df_subheader <- df%>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(subheader = paste("Group:", Group[1])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Group)

# Reorder dataframe by subheader
df_subheader <- df_subheader[order(df_subheader$subheader),]

# Print resulting dataframe
df_subheader  %>% view()
```

If I could also add a theme when saving in Excel would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution using a custom function to write lists with `openxlsx2` to demonstrate how I would approach the issue at hand. (I ordered the percentage values in a single column.)

```r
# example data
dat <- data.frame(
  Parameter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D"),
  Number = c(324, 173, 68, 396, NA, NA),
  HC = c(0, 1.3, 5.8, 3.1, 58, 100),
  Group = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4)
)

# split into list and prepare percentage output
dat$Group <- paste0("Group", dat$Group)
dat$HC <- dat$HC / 100
out <- split(dat[,-4] , f =  dat$Group)
for (i in seq_along(out)) {
  class(out[[i]]$HC) <- c(class(out[[i]]$HC), "percentage")
}


library(openxlsx2)

# custom helper function to write colored lists
wb_add_list <- function(wb, x) {
  wb <- wb$clone()
  row <- 1
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = names(x[i]), colNames = FALSE)
    wb$merge_cells(rows = row, cols = 1:3)
    dims <- paste0("A", row)
    wb$add_fill(dims =  dims, color = wb_color("red"))
    wb$add_font(dims =  dims, color = wb_color("white"))
    row <- row + 1L
    wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = x[[i]], colNames = FALSE)
    row <- row + nrow(x[[i]])
  }
  wb
}

wb <- wb_workbook() %>% wb_add_worksheet() %>% wb_add_list(x = out)
# wb %>% wb_save("test.xlsx")
# wb %>% wb_open()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do this type of contextual pivoting or row grouping in packages that export to Latex or HTML like `gt`. Unfortunately they do not export to xlsx formats.

To export this into Excel I usually recur to this custom function:

```
library(tidyverse)
pseudo_pivot_topleft <- function(df, groupby = "id") {

df_seq <-  rowid_to_column(df, var = "rowid")

df_pivotted <- 
  df %>% select(all_of(groupby)) %>% distinct() %>% add_column(rowid = 0, .before = 1) %>% 
  bind_rows( df_seq  ) %>% 
  arrange(across(all_of(groupby)), rowid) %>% 
  select(-rowid)

df_pivotted
}

pseudo_pivot_topleft(df,groupby = "Group")

pseudo_pivot_topleft(df,groupby = "Group") %>% 
    mutate(Parameter = if_else(is.na(Parameter), as.character(Group), Parameter)) %>% 
    select(-Group)

# A tibble: 10 × 4


   Parameter Number HC    Percentage
   <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>     
 1 1         NA     NA    NA        
 2 A         324    324   0%        
 3 B         173    12902 1.3%      
 4 2         NA     NA    NA        
 5 C         68     1166  5.8%      
 6 3         NA     NA    NA        
 7 D         396    12902 3.1%      
 8 E         58%    -     -         
 9 4         NA     NA    NA        
10 D         -100%  -     -
```